# How to obtain value from an array of struct? (C)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have been trying to access the values I have declared in an array of structure, as below.

```
struct info{
    int name[];
    int age[];
};

const struct info arr_info[] = {{Pat,15}, {Emily,4}, {Matt,22}};
```

I was using the following method, however, I found only the pointer is obtained. This is an issue as I'm trying to pass this value through to a function.

```
arr_info[2].age
```

What do I require in my code to access the value itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int x[]` does not mean what you think it does. This is a structure that's inside out. Get rid of those `[]` inside the definition.

Comment: What is `Pat`? Do you mean `"Pat"`?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

What you probably mean is this:

```c
// Define struct called "info"...
struct info {
    // ...with a character string property "name"...
    char* name;
    // ...and a single integer representing "age".
    int age;
};

const struct info arr_info[] = {{"Pat",15}, {"Emily",4}, {"Matt",22}};
```

What you had defined was an array of structures *with arrays in them*, which really doesn't make any sense given the intent on your assignment line. It implies each `info` struct can have *multiple names* and *multiple ages* when what you want is multiple `info` structs, each with *one* name and *one* age.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention in my post that my names were actually declared as ints earlier in the program.

Comment: If you want to use `int` instead of `char*` that's an easy fix.